# UITableViewCell content being cut

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a UITableView with the height as

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I found that characters, e.g. p, g, y, etc are being cut, which can't show correctly.

I've tried to set the height in larger number, however, the cell height will increase, but it is still didn't show the whole word.

Besides, I've tried something like setting a

```
label.sizeToFit()
cell.textlabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

But all doesn't work

[image]

Comment: What constraints are defined for the text label?

Comment: Should I use cell.textLabel?.addConstraint(bottomConstraint) ? I tried but it shows "Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint."

Comment: It looks like UILabel's height is not enough. If you're using autolayout, try to increase height constraint constant value

Comment: @alexburtnik I'm not using autolayout

Comment: are you changing font after this line: `label.sizeToFit()`?

Comment: No. I do it just before return cell. cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit() return cell

Comment: Can you add the constraints in the interface builder or just by code?

Answer (score 0):

sizeToFit is not meant to resize labels to match their font.  From the UIView header:

```
open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize // return 'best' size to fit given size. does not actually resize view. Default is return existing view size

open func sizeToFit() // calls sizeThatFits: with current view bounds and changes bounds size.
```

It's a relatively arbitrary method that just returns some kind of size.  If you want to find out how big to make a label, use
`string.boundingRect(with: CGSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions, attributes: [String : Any]?, context: NSStringDrawingContext?)`.  However, I find that it doesn't respect heights very well, so you are better off getting the ascender/descender from the font and calculating the size yourself.